# Custom agora sdk flutter with open cv and tensorflow

Tags: ios, tensorflow, opencv, flutter, agora.io

I want to use open cv and tensorflow for flutter agora sdk on ios, but I dont know how to import it. This is link repo `https://github.com/AgoraIO/Flutter-SDK`. Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example here: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart

To answer your question specifically, to import the SDK you need to add it to your pubspec.yml file in your Flutter project. This is where all the external packages are added.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: 3.2.0
  intl: ^0.15.8
  agora_rtc_engine: 1.0.5
  permission_handler: ^3.0.0
```

Depending on your development environment you will then have to prompt Flutter to get the dependencies by running `flutter pub get` or your IDE (Vscode, etc.) will detect the change and do it for you.

Comment: No I want to import c++ open cv and use it